# multiple row fetched with max number sql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max

I have two tables with the following records:

Clients:

```
cid | cname | ccountry
-----------------------
  1 | John  | Australia
  2 | Mark  | USA
  3 | Liz   | England
```

Orders:

```
oid | cid | oquantity
---------------------
  1 |   1 |       100
  2 |   1 |       100
  3 |   2 |        50
  4 |   2 |       150
  5 |   3 |        50
  6 |   3 |       100
```

I need to find out the Client name(s) who has maximum quantity of orders. I run the following query and got the correct result.

```
select cname, ccountry
  from Clients
 where cid in
         (select cid
            from Orders
        group by cid
          having sum(oquantity) = (select max(amount) from
                                       (select sum(oquantity) amount
                                          from Orders
                                        group by cid)t1))
```

2 row(s) returned

> 'John', 'Australia'
>
> 'Mark', 'USA'

But I just need to know, whether it can be done by more simple way. It has become complicated once total quantity is also required to be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reduced your `2` Subqueries.

```
SELECT
  clients.cid,
  cname,
  ccountry
FROM Orders,
  Clients
WHERE orders.cid = clients.cid
GROUP BY clients.cid
HAVING SUM(orders.oquantity) = (SELECT
                                  SUM(oquantity) AS amount
                                FROM Orders
                                GROUP BY cid
                                ORDER BY amount DESC
                                LIMIT 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.cname, c.ccountry, SUM(oquantity) AS total_qtty
FROM Clients c
INNER JOIN Orders o ON (o.cid = c.cid)
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY total_qtty DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: not needed, only if you want to restrict how many results you want to bring out.

Comment: But I want to get all records matching with max. In this case, LIMIT will not work.

Comment: My intention was to find out only the records for which the total quantity equals the maximum total quantity. For example if you extract orders table you will find that cid 1 and 2 have a total quantity of 200 while cid 3 has 150. So, it is required to write a query which fetch cid 1 and 2 only but not 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
select cname, ccountry, sum(oquantity)
FROM Clients c
INNER JOIN Orders o ON (o.cid = c.cid)
where c.cid in 
(
  select cid from Orders group by cid 
   having sum(oquantity) = (
     select max(amount) from (
        select sum(oquantity) amount from Orders group by cid)t1))
GROUP BY c.cid
```